# ASP.NET show ModalPopupExtender from Buttons created in Code-Behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, modalpopupextender, code-behind

Hi I have a modalPopupExtender in my aspx web page pointing to a Panel and in Code-Behind I create buttons which I want them to show the modalPopup, so I have:

```
buttonX.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get(" + modalPopup.ClientID + ").show();";
```

but instead it just does a PostBack, even if I put "return false;" at the end of the past code.

Comment: Are you sure that adding `return false;` is not working?  I just opened a project in Visual Studio and ran a quick test with a JavaScript alert box and `return false;` prevents the postback.

Comment: @Infotekka the return false on its own worked but what was wrong was the other syntax which never got to the return false part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have figured something out although I'm not sure it's the best solution.

This is my code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Text = "Hello World!";
        btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get('" + HiddenField.ClientID + "').click(); return false;";
        PanelHello.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

and this is my ASPX page:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" />
<asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="HiddenField"
    PopupControlID="Panel" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" />
<asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server">
    <h1>
        Hello World!</h1>
</asp:Panel>
```

And this makes the modal pop up **without posting back** =D!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
buttonX.OnClick = "javascript: preventDefault(); $get(" + modalPopup.ClientID + ").show();";
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't help, it still just does PostBack ignoring that javascript.

Comment: Plus it has to be OnClientClick, OnClick can't be done, only Click and it has to be by an EventHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see your problem.  You aren't quoting the ClientID in your JS call, so it's actually just failing - that's why `return false` isn't working either.  If the only issue was the postback you should still see your popup before the page posts back to itself.

Your code:

```
buttonX.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get(" + modalPopup.ClientID + ").show();";
```

Will add `"javascript:$get(ctl123).show();"` (I'm using ctl123 as a placeholder name for whatever your ClientID is) - the idea is the error is happening because what you should have is this:

```
buttonX.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get('" + modalPopup.ClientID + "').show();";
```

Which will output `"javascript:$get('ctl123').show();"`

The difference being that in the second one the control ID is quoted.

Give that a try, and add `return false;` to prevent the postback.  Like so:

```
buttonX.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get('" + modalPopup.ClientID + "').show(); return false;";
```

Comment: I have

`protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();
            btn.Text = "Hello World!";
            btn.OnClientClick = "javascript:$get('" + modalPopup.ClientID + "').show();return false;";
            PanelHello.Controls.Add(btn);
        }`

Comment: and

`<h2>
                Hello World!</h2>
            <br />
            <asp:Panel ID="PanelHello" runat="server">
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField" runat="server" />
            <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="HiddenField"
                PopupControlID="Panel" DynamicServicePath="" Enabled="True" />
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel" runat="server">
                <h1>
                    HOLA!</h1>
            </asp:Panel>`

And still isn't working.

Comment: Are you looking to see if your page is producing any JavaScript errors?